# Laravel 5 custom package class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating laravel 5.2 package, following are my files

packages/
-Shreeji/
--Ring/
---composer.json
---src/
----Ring.php
----RingModel.php
----RingServiceProvider

composer.json

```
{
 "name": "shreeji/ring",
 "description": "Simple",
 "license": "MIT",
 "authors": [
     {
         "name": "author",
         "email": "email@gmail.com"
     }
 ],
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
             "Shreeji\\Ring\\": "src/"
         }
     },
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
 "require": {
     "Illuminate/support": "~5"
 }
}
```

Ring.php

```
namespace Shreeji\Ring;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

Class Ring {

private $ringmodel;
protected $table_name = null;


function __construct() {

}

function set_table($table_name)
{
    $this->table_name = $table_name;
    $this->ringmodel = New RingModel($this->table_name);
    return $this;
}

}
```

RingModel.php

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class RingModel extends Eloquent {

// Set table name;
protected $table;
protected $primary_key;

public function __construct($table)
{
    $this->table = $table;
}
}
```

RingServiceProvider.php

```
namespace Shreeji\Ring;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

Class RingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('ring', function($app){
        return new Ring;
    });
}

public function boot()
{

}
}
```

And in app/Http/Controllers I have created test file like this

RingController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Shreeji\Ring;

class RingController extends Controller
{

 public function index()
 {
     $ring = New Ring();
     $ring->set_table('ring');
 }
}
```

In Routes.php

```
Route::get('ringtest', [ 'as' => 'ringtest', 'uses' => 'RingController@index' ]);
```

I have added service provider in config/app.php as

```
Shreeji\Ring\RingServiceProvider::class,
```

In composer.json I have added this as

```
.....
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Shreeji\\Ring\\": "packages/Shreeji/Ring/src"
    }
.....
```

When I call ringtest from browser I get following error.

FatalErrorException in RingController.php line 19: Class 'Shreeji\Ring' not found

What is wrong with my code why this class is not found I have also run composer dumpautoload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller you have:

```
use Shreeji\Ring;
```

But, it must be:

```
use Shreeji\Ring\Ring;
```

The first 'Ring' is directory (namespace). The second 'Ring' is the class.

Your model is not in your namespace. The first line of your model must be:

```
namespace Shreeji\Ring;
```

Comment: Thanks for this its work. but now I am getting error in Ring.php about FatalErrorException in Ring.php line 21: Class 'Shreeji\Ring\RingModel' not found can you help me with that too

Comment: That's right, the first line of your model must be: namespace Shreeji\Ring;  So your model is in your namespace.

Comment: I hate laravel for this reason. The complexity and sensitivity of the loading mechanisms is ridiculous/

Comment: The loading is more of a php / composer thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your namespaces are correct except when your importing the **Ring** class to your Ring controller

In your Ring controller change

```
use Shreeji\Ring;
```

to

```
use Shreeji\Ring\Ring;
```

where the first **Ring** is the folder and the second **Ring** is the class.

Next on the first line of your file add a namespace for your **RingModel** class

```
namespace Shreeji\Ring;
```

and add

```
use Shreeji\Ring\RingModel;
```

to the **Ring** class to import the **RingModel** class.

Then in your package's composer file change

```
"Shreeji\\Ring\\": "src/"
```

to

```
"Shreeji\\": "packages/shreeji/ring/src"
```

After that navigate to your package's directory and run

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

in your terminal or command prompt  to regenerate **composer.json** file .

Next add

```
"Shreeji\\": "packages/shreeji/ring/src"
```

to your Laravel application's **composer.json** file inside the `autoload psr-4` array and then switch to your Laravel's application folder and run

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

in your terminal or command prompt to regenerate **composer.json** file.

Here is a link on Laravel package development.

[Laravel Package Development](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages)